# Year and day of year to date using Date::Calc

Tags: perl

How do you get the date from year and day of year using [`Date::Calc`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Calc)?

I managed to figure it out using `DateTime` but I need to use `Date::Calc`.

The following works, but I don't know how to get it working using `Date::Calc`.

```
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->from_day_of_year(
    year        => 2018,
    day_of_year => 70,
);

# Prints the correct date of March something.
print($dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d') . "\n");
```

What I have so far is

```
 use Date::Calc 'Add_Delta_Days';

 my $dt = Add_Delta_Days(2018, 70);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documented usage is

> `($year,$month,$day) = Add_Delta_Days($year,$month,$day, $Dd);`

So

```
my ($y,$m,$d) = Add_Delta_Days(2018,1,1,70-1);
```

Note that the 70th day is 69 days after the 1st, thus the use of `70-1`.